# Dynamic condition in MySQL Group By

Tags: mysql

I have one table named viewlist as follows

```
 Id            article_id           viewdate
--------------------------------------------------
 1                1                2015-07-01
 2                1                2015-07-01
 3                1                2015-07-01
 4                2                2015-07-01
 5                2                2015-07-01
 6                1                2015-07-02
 7                2                2015-07-02
 8                1                2015-07-03
 9                2                2015-07-03
10                1                2015-07-08
11                1                2015-07-08
```

---

i need to write a MySQL query to get count and article_id by grouping adjacent viewdate field

wanted result as follows

```
article_id            count                   date_period
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1                   4                2015-07-01 - 2015-07-02
 2                   3                2015-07-01 - 2015-07-02
 1                   3                2015-07-03 - 2015-07-08
 2                   1                2015-07-03 - 2015-07-08
```

Is there any simple query to get this type of result?

Comment: There is definitely a query to get your result, but I don't expect it to be simple.

Comment: @Strawberry  help me to get this query

Comment: @Tech why  article_id  4 +3 but not 7 ?

Comment: @Strawberry result set derived by grouping adjacent dates

Comment: @splash58 it is because group by article_id

Comment: @Strawberry. it is because 2 already counted with 1    and      3/7/2015 adjacent to 8/7/15 because there is no record on 4/7/15, 5/7/15, 6/7/15  and 7/7/15

Comment: @Tech ^ then it should be 1-3 and 8-8 ?

Comment: I think you should amend your question accordingly.

Comment: 1st date to 2nd date, 3rd date to 4th date, 5th date to 6th date ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query may be usefull. but iam not sure this may or maynot be practical for large application

```
 SELECT a.range_start
 , a.range_end
 , b.article_id
 , COUNT(b.article_id) total
FROM 
 ( SELECT x.viewdate range_start
        , COALESCE(MIN(y.viewdate),MAX(x.viewdate)) range_end
        , @i:=@i+1 i 
     FROM my_table x 
     LEFT
     JOIN my_table y 
       ON y.viewdate > x.viewdate
     JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
    GROUP   
       BY range_start 
   HAVING MOD(i,2) = 1
 ) a
LEFT
JOIN my_table b
ON b.viewdate BETWEEN a.range_start AND a.range_end
GROUP
BY article_id
 , range_start;
```

Answer (score 3):

My original solution apparently had some problem with variable initialisation.

I'm guessing that the amended solution below gets around this problem.

It uses one slight hack, which might fail on future versions of MySQL(-type) systems, but it's easy to workaround if needs be - just changing the HAVING in the subquery to a WHERE in the super query and adding an ORDER BY somewhere...

```
SELECT a.range_start
     , a.range_end
     , b.article_id
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.viewdate range_start
            , MIN(y.viewdate) range_end
            , @i:=@i+1 i 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.viewdate > x.viewdate
         JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        GROUP   
           BY range_start 
       HAVING MOD(i,2) = 1
     ) a
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.viewdate BETWEEN a.range_start AND a.range_end
 GROUP
    BY article_id
     , range_start;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d753f/3

In response to comments below, something like the following might be a way to handle 'unpaired' range_starts - but it's not tested...

```
SELECT a.range_start
     , a.range_end
     , b.article_id
     , COUNT(b.article_id) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.viewdate range_start
            , COALESCE(MIN(y.viewdate),MAX(x.viewdate)) range_end
            , @i:=@i+1 i 
         FROM my_table x 
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.viewdate > x.viewdate
         JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        GROUP   
           BY range_start 
       HAVING MOD(i,2) = 1
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.viewdate BETWEEN a.range_start AND a.range_end
 GROUP
    BY article_id
     , range_start;
```

Comment: it doesn't provide any result. why?

Comment: it is working now, thanks so much.. if we add one more record with date 2015-07-08 to the table . then with this query last added record will not come in result set because there is no record to combine with 2015-07-08. is there any solution to solve this by adding 2015-07-09 date in query (not in table) ?

Comment: @Tech an outer join in the subquery I guess - but I'm not sure I understand how you'd want to handle dates falling within an indeterminate range

Answer (score 2):

```
select article_id, count(article_id), concat(min(viewdate),' - ', max(viewdate)) from `tablename` group by article_id
```

Try this it may be work.

Comment: it gives `1    7 2015-07-01 2015-07-08,  2   4 2015-07-01 2015-07-03`